# Disable cygwin temporarily

Tags: cygwin

I want to disable cygwin temporarily without uninstalling it (e.g. for the duration of a batch script).

I was hoping there is a simple way, e.g. an environment variable like

```
$> SET cygwin=OFF
```

or an internal cygwin command like

```
$> cygset off
```

Right now I am using a quick and dirty solution that simply invalidates the cygwin directory in the Windows path with

```
SET PATH=%PATH:Cygwin=%
```

Of course this will also corrupt other pathes that have `Cygwin` in it.

Comment: It seems that you just need to remove the Cywin dir from your PATH

Comment: Yes, that works. I was wondering if there is a builtin switch?